# SQL - moving data from one table to another - referencing data

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures

I have a SQL table **AccessLog**, with following columns and sample data:

```
| id | firstName | lastName | userEmail   | loginTimestamp           |
| -- | --------- | -------- | ----------- | ------------------------ |
| 1  | John      | Smith    | smith@wp.pl | 2021-01-12T02:16:34.020Z | 
| 2  | ED        | Stone    | stone@wp.pl | 2021-02-12T02:26:34.020Z |  
| 3  | ED        | Stone    | stone@wp.pl | 2021-03-12T02:36:34.020Z |
```

I'd like to extract 3 columns (firstName, lastName, userEmail) and move it to separate table **Client**.
**Client** should look like this then:

```
| id    | firstName | lastName | userEmail   |
| ----- | --------- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1001  | John      | Smith    | smith@wp.pl | 
| 1002  | ED        | Stone    | stone@wp.pl |
```

The point is I need a connection between **AccessLog** and **Client** table, which should look this way:

```
| id | clientId  | loginTimestamp           |
| -- | --------- | ------------------------ |
| 1  | 1001      | 2021-01-12T02:16:34.020Z | 
| 2  | 1002      | 2021-02-12T02:26:34.020Z |  
| 3  | 1002      | 2021-03-12T02:36:34.020Z |
```

AccessLog should reference to **Client** table through **clientId** field.

I know how to copy data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO Client (firstName, lastName, userEmail) 
SELECT DISTINCT firstName, lastName, userEmail FROM AccessLog
```

but how to make a connection between both tables without loosing any data?
Can anybody help?

Comment: Where do the `id` values in the `Client` table come from?

Comment: It is a primary key, it will be auto-incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use a `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` so that you can get the new and old ids.

This works without more code as you have only distinct values in your new client list.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE AccessLog
>     (`id` varchar(2), `firstName` varchar(9), `lastName` varchar(8), `userEmail` varchar(11), `loginTimestamp` varchar(24))
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO AccessLog
>     (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `userEmail`, `loginTimestamp`)
> VALUES
>     ('1', 'John', 'Smith', 'smith@wp.pl', '2021-01-12T02:16:34.020Z'),
>     ('2', 'ED', 'Stone', 'stone@wp.pl', '2021-02-12T02:26:34.020Z'),
>     ('3', 'ED', 'Stone', 'stone@wp.pl', '2021-03-12T02:36:34.020Z')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Client
>     (`id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `firstName` varchar(9), `lastName` varchar(8), `userEmail` varchar(11))
> ;
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE Table bridgetable (id BIGINT , clientId  BIGINT , loginTimestamp varchar(24))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER after_client_insert
> AFTER INSERT
> ON Client FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     
>         INSERT INTO bridgetable(id, clientId,loginTimestamp)
>         SELECT 
>            `id`, new.id,loginTimestamp 
>         FROM AccessLog WHERE `firstName` = NEW.`firstName` AND `lastName` = NEW.`lastName`
>         AND `userEmail` = NEW.`userEmail`;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Client (firstName, lastName, userEmail) 
> SELECT DISTINCT firstName, lastName, userEmail FROM AccessLog
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Client
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstName | lastName | userEmail  
> -: | :-------- | :------- | :----------
>  1 | John      | Smith    | smith@wp.pl
>  2 | ED        | Stone    | stone@wp.pl
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM bridgetable
> ```
>
> ```
> id | clientId | loginTimestamp          
> -: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 |        1 | 2021-01-12T02:16:34.020Z
>  2 |        2 | 2021-02-12T02:26:34.020Z
>  3 |        2 | 2021-03-12T02:36:34.020Z
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f973354ef7e7edffb45eeed3658a01ba)*